# Migrate Missing Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 914 stored procedures that I need to shuffle between two databases.

62 stored procedures on Server1 that are not on Server2, and 790 that are on Server2 that are not on Server1.

I know exactly what stored procedures are missing, as I ran this query to find them:

```
DECLARE @Routine varchar (20) = 'Procedure' --'Function'
    --,@What VARCHAR(200) = '%Survey%'

select SPECIFIC_CATALOG
    ,SPECIFIC_NAME
    ,SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
    --,@@servername AS [Server Name]
    ,'[Server1]' AS [Server Name]
    ,ROUTINE_TYPE
    ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    ,CREATED
    ,LAST_ALTERED 

 from [Server1].Database1.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = @Routine
--AND SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE @What
AND specific_name NOT IN (SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME

                            from [Server2.Database1.information_schema.routines 
                            where routine_type = @Routine
                                --AND SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE @What
                                ) 

UNION all
select SPECIFIC_CATALOG
    ,SPECIFIC_NAME
    ,SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
    --,@@servername AS [Server Name]
    ,'[Server2]' AS [Server Name]
    ,ROUTINE_TYPE
    ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    ,CREATED
    ,LAST_ALTERED 
 from [Server2].Database1.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = @Routine
--AND SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE @What
AND specific_name NOT IN (SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME

                            from [Server1].Database1.information_schema.routines 
                            where routine_type = @Routine
                                --AND SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE @What
                                )
```

Is there a way to modify this to take the result set and have it automatically move the stored procedures to the server where they are not?

I do not need to migrate "every" stored procedure on Server1 or Server2, just the ones that are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to create a SQL Server Database Project in the Visual Studio IDE that comes with SQL Server 2008

once you create the project and the connection, you can do a database compare.

When the compare is complete, it will show you the differences in the databases and by default will already pre setup to execute to want to copy over what is missing from one to the other, and if there are things you do not want, and you can actually pick and choose with a checkboxes which you would like to have copied and executed over to the T.   Just make sure you tell the comparison options you only care about objects, not logins, and other odds and ends that come with SQL Server.

This is what I would do in your situation.  Although going T-SQL it is not impossible either.  I only answering this because this option and Visual Studio IDE does come with the install of SQL Server 2008, and there is no coding involved.